# Pushing new Rails 3.1 app to Heroku causing problems with Sorcery mod (requiring bson-1.4.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, authentication, heroku, bson

I have an app that runs great locally. Everything seems to be set up correctly to transfer over to Heroku, including the Postgres gem (and dev was done using a postgres server).

The problem is, when I try to push it up, I get error messages surrounding the three currently problematic dependencies, bson_ext, bson, and mongoid, 1.4.1.  It seems that Sorcery requires these (at 1.4.1) to run.  I got them installed locally by downloading the manually, but they were yanked from the online sources.  So when Heroku tries to find them, it can't, and it aborts.  I tried specifying to use 1.4.0 for all of them, and the app then installs fine (and does the database setup stuff for the Cedar stack, etc).

The problem is that when I load the app on their server, I get the generic "oops, there's been a problem" Heroku message.  Upon checking the actual heroku log, I can't really find anything wrong.  What is the way to make this work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, and I was able to get past it by specifying version 1.3.1 for the mongo, bson, and bson_ext gems. I just put this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongo', '1.3.1'
gem 'bson', '1.3.1'
gem 'bson_ext', '1.3.1'
```